# How to use Vert.x event loop to schedule RxJava execution

Tags: rx-java, vert.x

Is it possible to use Vert.x event loop as scheduler for RxJava execution? Something like...

```
Observable.range(1, 10).flatMap(it ->
  Observable.just(it)
).subscribeOn(new VertxScheduler()).
  subscribe(System.out::println);
```

...where `VertxScheduler` should be some kind of Vert.x event loop based scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [in Vert.x RxJava documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/#_scheduler_support) you can create Vert.x based scheduler using `io.vertx.reactivex.RxHelper`:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
Scheduler scheduler = RxHelper.scheduler(vertx);

Observable.range(1, 10).flatMap(it ->
  Observable.just(it)
).subscribeOn(scheduler).
  subscribe(System.out::println);
```

There is also `RxHelper.blockingScheduler(Vertx)` method creating scheduler from Vert.x worker threads pool.